# Store Multiple checkboxes values in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

Below is the complete code of adding a new product in the database and it works.

```
I've 3 tables "Product","Category" and "SubCategory".

I've 5 Categories "Electronics","Clothing","Sports","Books" and "Others".
```

I want to add a 3 checkboxes of sizes: small,medium & large and I want these checkboxes as hidden unless I select "Clothing" category from dropdownlist. When I select Clothing from category dropdown the size checkboxes should appear so I can select size:small checkbox or may be both size:small and size:medium checkboxes and I want this to be stored in database. I don't think both values of checkboxes can be stored in one single row of database.

**Example**

```
productid = 1

product name= polo t-shirt

sizes: small & medium (both checkboxes are checked)
```

and I want the available sizes in a dropdownlist when viewing the product details for add to cart function.

I've a **product model**:

```
public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal? Price { get; set; }

    public int? Quantity { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Submitted { get; set; }

    public int? StoreId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DeliveryDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ShippingCharges { get; set; }

    public int? SubCategoryId { get; set; }

    public int? ProvinceId { get; set; }

    public int? CityId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual City City { get; set; }

    public virtual Province Province { get; set; }

    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
```

**product controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "StoreOwner")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddProduct(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        List<string> DeliveryDate = new List<string>();
        DeliveryDate.Add("1-2 Days");
        DeliveryDate.Add("3-5 Days");
        DeliveryDate.Add("1 Week");
        SelectList dd = new SelectList(DeliveryDate);
        ViewBag.DeliveryDate = dd;

        List<string> PaymentMethods = new List<string>();
        PaymentMethods.Add("Cash on Delivery");
        SelectList pm = new SelectList(PaymentMethods);
        ViewBag.PaymentMethods = pm;

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> provinces = db.Provinces.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.ProvinceId.ToString(),
            Text = c.ProvinceName

        });
        ViewBag.ProvinceId = provinces;

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cities = db.Cities.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.CityId.ToString(),
            Text = c.CityName

        });
        ViewBag.CityId = cities;

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categories = db.Categories.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.CategoryId.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name

        });

        ViewBag.CategoryId = categories;

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> subcategories = db.SubCategories.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.SubCatId.ToString(),
            Text = c.SubCatName

        });
        ViewBag.SubCategoryId = subcategories;


        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> stores = db.Stores.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.StoreId.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name

        });
        ViewBag.Stores = stores;

         if (file != null)
            {
                string ImagePath = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages/" + ImagePath);

                file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

                //save new record in database
                Product newRecord = new Product();
                newRecord.Name = Request.Form["Name"];
                newRecord.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["CategoryId"]);
                newRecord.SubCategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["SubCategoryId"]);
                newRecord.StoreId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Stores"]);
                newRecord.Description = Request.Form["Description"];
                newRecord.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form["Price"]);
                newRecord.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Quantity"]);
                newRecord.ProvinceId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ProvinceId"]);
                newRecord.CityId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["CityId"]);
                newRecord.ShippingCharges = Request.Form["ShippingCharges"];
                newRecord.DeliveryDate = Request.Form["DeliveryDate"];
                newRecord.PaymentMethod = Request.Form["PaymentMethods"];
                newRecord.ImagePath = ImagePath;
                newRecord.Submitted = DateTime.Now;
                db.Products.Add(newRecord);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("OwnerManage","Manage");
            }

        return View();
    }
```

**view**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Store", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data",   @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<h4>Create a new product.</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label", data_val_required = "required" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Name)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CategoryId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryId, ViewBag.CategoryId as SelectList, new { @class = "CssCategory" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubCategoryId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label subcatshow" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SubCategoryId, ViewBag.SubCategoryId as SelectList, new { @class = "CssSubCategory" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StoreId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Stores", "Select a Value")
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProvinceId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProvinceId, ViewBag.ProvinceId as SelectList, new { @class = "CssProvince" })

    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CityId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label cityshow" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CityId, ViewBag.CityId as SelectList, new { @class = "CssCity" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Quantity, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Quantity, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DeliveryDate, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("DeliveryDate", ViewBag.DeliveryDate as SelectList)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ShippingCharges, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ShippingCharges, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PaymentMethod, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("PaymentMethods", ViewBag.PaymentMethods as SelectList)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImagePath, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create Product" />
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Comment: It it really necessary to dump all this code in the question? Just show the relevant code and you will have a better chance that someone will look at it. Refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As for how to solve this, one option would be make your property an enum with a `[Flags]` attribute  or a string where you store the values as a comma separated list, and use a view model to represent the checkboxes which you then map back to the property

Answer (score 3):

There are many things you can do. A couple are:

A. You can add three properties of type `bool?` named small medium and large to your product object.

B. You can create a size object with the three size properties also of type `bool?` and then add the size object to your product object.

Then on the view you can use jquery to toggle their visibility depending on what product type they selected.

It's really up to you how you want to handle storing it.

A. If you have to use only one row in a table, you can store a string to parse like "S;L" and split/join by ';'.

B. You could also do something ridiculous and create a new table that has every possible selection variation and assign each one an ID and pass the ID into the single row on the other table.

C. I would personally create a new table that took in the product ID as a foreign key and have 3 columns for each size as a `bool`.

However, I'm not sure what way would be considered 'good practice'.

Comment: I will try to create a new table. Thanks for the ideas you suggested!

Comment: You're welcome. Just so you know, since you're using MVC, you can clean your controller up a lot. MVC does quite a bit of work for you as far as binding objects. For instance, in your controller's post, instead of taking in just the `HttpPostedFileBase file`, take in your product model as well. `public ActionResult AddProduct(HttpPostedFileBase file, Product newProduct)`